# Internet Explorer xx.yy website issue

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

If you have site following this pattern(http://xx.yy/ ) internet explorer does not hold any cookies . Any solution ?

For example:

- http://co.uk
- http://gc.ca
- http://on.ca

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give some sample URLs?

Comment: It may be useful to provide some kind of network dump (like from Fiddler).

Comment: two letter domains ending in .mk

Comment: It's a pitfall making two- and one-letter domains less useful. It's happened to me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is essentially by-design. The workaround is to put a "www" before xx.yy.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/19/Private-Domain-Names-and-Public-Suffixes-in-Internet-Explorer.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310676

http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/ie-and-2-letter-domain-names.html

Comment: I've provided the workaround. Either you can use it, or you can wander the Internet, trying to find another solution. Since I've reviewed the WinINET code, I can tell you that such efforts will be fruitless.

Comment: Interested to know what you think of the approach I've listed below.

Answer (score 7):

Hmm.

So this interested me, and Eric Law is correct, however I have another work around that he does not seem to have listed.

Instead of:

```
http://aa.mk/
```

Make your url

```
http://aa.mk./
```

Note `'.'` as suffix.

It will go to the same website, and, as far as I've just tested, you can set cookies on this domain.

I verified in IE6 using the JavaScript cookie-setting code [here](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php) passing the domain as "`aa.mk.`".

Comment: From what I know, `aa.mk.` if the official form and `aa.mk` is just a well-accepted shortcut to that syntax.