# InternetSetCookie in C# Application doesn't work with Subdomains

Tags: c#, cookies, browser, webclient, webrequest

In my C# Application I am navigating through a website using HTTPWebrequest etc.
At a certain point I want to display the Website in a WebBrowser Control.

The current Cookies are saved in a CookieContainer.

The following code works perfect, all Cookies were sent in the Requests by the browser.

```
CookieCollection cookies = ck.GetCookies(new Uri("http://www.abcde.de"));

foreach (Cookie c in cookies) {
  if (!InternetSetCookie("http://www.abcde.de", c.Name, c.Value))
    throw new Exception("Exception setting cookie: Win32 Error code=" 
    + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
  }

  /** Setting header_infos, POST-Data etc **/
  webBrowser1.Navigate(link, "_self", parameterbyte, header_infos.ToString());
```

But when I retrieve the Cookies from a Subdomain like

```
CookieCollection cookies = ck.GetCookies(new Uri("http://ab.cde.de"));
```

the IntersetSetCookie Function throws an exception because the URL-Format "http://ab.cde.de" is not valid. When I try "http://www.cde.de" or "http://www.ab.cde.de" instead I dont get an exception but the website doesn't load correctly because the browser only sends one of the five cookies in the request and I don't know why.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this behavior is intentional for security reasons. Site on subdomain could be hosted on completely different server managed by completely different person than site on main domain. Cookies can potentially contain sensitive information so web browser prevent sending them to another (sub)domain.

Comment: yeah I already thought something like that. But how can I set a Cookie to http://abc.de when InternetSetCookie("http://abc.de",...) doesn t work?

Comment: There in [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189638/internet-explorer-xx-yy-website-problem) on SO. Also check [this FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx) which explains this behavior in more detail.